# Find the last row of the datagrid and add information

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have the following procedure:

```
Private Sub btnProcessOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcessOrder.Click

    Dim dblTipAmount As Double = CDbl(txtTipAmount.Text)

    frmPlaceOrder.grdNewInvoice.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "Tips"
    frmPlaceOrder.grdNewInvoice.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = 1
    frmPlaceOrder.grdNewInvoice.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = dblTipAmount

End Sub
```

It works fine, but it writes the data to the first line of the datagrid. My datagrid is already populated so it replaces what I have there, instead I want to added to the below the last populated line on my datagrid.

Please help

Comment: For unbound DGV you can use AddRow ..

Comment: @matzone, Thank you I didn't even think of that. It worked just great